# WPF Code-behind Expander won't expand

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, stackpanel, expander

I'm filling a StackPanel with Expanders, yet they don't seem to expand. I've gone about testing its Button.Click event to ensure all is functioning as it should (which it is), so I don't understand why it won't expand. The above-mentioned StackPanel is the content of a SurfaceScrollViewer, and when the Expander is expanded the normal behavior (as demonstrated in Blend) is to align the ToggleButton/Header to the top of the SurfaceScrollViewer. I'm relatively new to the WPF, so perhaps I'm missing something small? Is there more to this auto-align/focus behavior?

XAML:

```
<s:SurfaceScrollViewer Name="TimeScrollViewer" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="#4CAAAAFF" Style="{DynamicResource SurfaceScrollViewerHorizontalTop}" Foreground="#4CAAAAFF">
    <StackPanel Name="TimeStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</s:SurfaceScrollViewer>
```

C#:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += delegate
    {
        PopulateScrollViewer(new string[] { "5:00", "5:30", "6:00", "6:30", "7:00", "7:30", "8:00", "8:30", "9:00", "9:30" });
    };
}

public void PopulateScrollViewer(string [] contents)
{
    Style expanderStyle = FindResource("SurfaceExpander") as Style;

    foreach (string s in contents)
    {
        Expander expander = new Expander();

        expander.Style = FindResource("SurfaceExpander") as Style;
        expander.Header = s;
        expander.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        expander.FontSize = 21.333;
        expander.Width = TimeScrollViewer.ActualWidth * 0.25;
        expander.Height = TimeScrollViewer.ActualHeight * 0.4;

        Label label = new Label();

        label.Content = "test";

        expander.Content = label;

        TimeStackPanel.Children.Add(expander);
    } 
}
```

I'd rather not bombard you with the entire style(s), but the "SurfaceScrollViewerHorizontalTop" places the horizontal scroll bar atop the content, and the "SurfaceExpander" removes the indication arrow.

Comment: Delete all that ugly code and use an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Any suggested tutorials behind binding? I'm not the most familiar with it.

Comment: http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/

Comment: Thanks a lot HC! I don't use Stack overflow often, is there any way I can commend you for your assistance?